# Best way to ease back into body building routine after a long break

Tags: bodybuilding, rest

Do you guys have some recommendation on how to "get back" into the training?

Sometimes I have to stay few weeks without training, when I am on holidays for example.

I usually have **two weeks of light training** before starting with a proper body building routine, since I do not want to be very sore or injure myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some things I do (this is strength training, not body building, though):

- If I missed one or two workouts, repeat the last completed workout (not increasing weights on any of my lifts).
- If I miss more than that, I deload 5-10% and just slowly rebuild as my program would normally progress.
- If I miss a lot of time (usually just on one exercise due to an injury), I start over very light, even with the empty bar. I get back to my former weight much quicker than the first time through because I plateau less, and my form is already good, so it's not as much a set-back as you might think.